# Add additional button next to back button on Tab embedded in navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a storyboard that looks like the image shown[image: storyboard].
The single navigation controller manages my drill down navigation adds a Back button to all of the views 1,2,3 and 4 as I drill down.
What I would like to do, is add an additional button on the "back" nav bar on the right for each of the 3 tab views (2,3 and 4)
Can this be done in Swift?
Can anyone help?  I cannot add it using the storyboard as the button just seems to disappear on the storyboard and does not get displayed when I run the app.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to add another *back* button; you want to add a *right* bar button item. You can do this either in code or in the storyboard.

In code, you need to do something like:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Some Title", style: .Plain, target: self, action: <your-selector>)
```

where the `target` and `action` point to some method on your view controller (or on another object, if that's how you've set it up).

In the storyboard,

1. If the view controllers don't already have one, drag a `UINavigationItem` to each view controller.
2. Drag a `UIBarButtonItem` onto the right side of each view controller's navigation bar.

[image]

3. Configure the title or image of the button.

[image]

4. Control-drag from the right bar button item to the view controller that it's in and select the `IBAction` method that you want to be fired when the button is tapped.

Comment: I have tried that, and it appears to look good on the storyboard, but when I run the app, only the back button appears,  The new Titled UINaviatiionItem and the UIBarButtonItem are not displayed.

Comment: Are you sure that you're in a navigation controller?

Comment: I get back buttons so I assume that I am in a Navigation controller but I have never done anything that drills down like this to a tab bar.  I have uploaded a sample project here (http://www2.createchsol.com/testNavigation.zip) (very basic) to show you what I get if anyone can help, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Try dragging a Bar Button Item, not UI button. and you can set the titles of the buttons in view did load of each controller or even create the button in code. Here is how to do that

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "VC1 bar button", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "The action function name")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

Comment: when I try to drag a bar button item on to the view's back navigation bar, it replaces the tab icon button in the bottom toolbar and does not get added to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your viewDidLoad()

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Custom, target: self, action: "*add a func saying what you want the button to do*")
```

Example:

```
func save() {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image!, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
}
```

So in this case, I would say:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Custom, target: self, action: "save")
```

I hope this helps!

Note: You won't be able to see it in the storyboard, only when you run the app

Comment: Nope.  Button still does not show.  Only the back button.  I have a sample project here with the storyboard created.  Run the project and you will see that navigation bar does not show the title or right buttons for the tab bar views. (http://www2.createchsol.com/testNavigation.zip)

Comment: @StewartLynch I have the exact code in my app and it works. Add it to your viewDidLoad and you will see a bottom on the right side of the embedded navigation controller.

Comment: I did and still no button

Comment: @StewartLynch did you add it to your view did load? How about this. Send me your Xcode project and I will add the button for you. Then, I will send the updated version back

Comment: @StewartLynch ok. Send me your project and I will fix it for you

Comment: Also would you mind taking a look at my question and seeing if you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: @user457957 you can get the paired down project here (http://www2.createchsol.com/testNavigation.zip)  Thanks in advance.  I am stumped

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do that

```
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "YourImage"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(yourClass.yourFunction(_:)))

self.navigationController?.topViewController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Add this code and all the view controllers you want to add a right button besides the back button.

I hope that this code help you!